# Greasemonkey AJAX return's abort() is not a function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, greasemonkey, gm-xmlhttprequest

Basically, I try to send a request via the `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` Greasemonkey API and abort it.

Here is a demo script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            example
// @namespace       example795cb636-1f35
// @include         https://www.google.com/
// ==/UserScript==

var ret = GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://www.google.com/",
    onerror: function(response) {
        console.log("error : " + response.statusText);
    },
    onabort: function(response) {
        console.log("abort : " + response.statusText);
    },
    onload: function(response) {
        console.log("complete : " + response.statusText);
    }
});

try{
    ret.abort();
}
catch(e){
    console.log(ret);
    console.log(e);
}
```

Here is my console output:
[image]

What am I missing?

*Details:*

<sup>Firefox 20.0a1

Greasemonkey 1.5</sup>

Comment: If anyone is wondering, [the return value](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest#Returns) is always supposed to have a method called `abort`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**
Submitted a patch that was [rolled into GM version 1.9](http://www.greasespot.net/2013/05/greasemonkey-19-release.html).  This issue is now officially resolved.

---

This is a bug in Greasemonkey.  In [Greasemonkey's `xmlhttprequester.js` source](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/master/modules/xmlhttprequester.js), `abort` is [not exposed properly, per Mozilla's COW interface](https://wiki.mozilla.org/XPConnect_Chrome_Object_Wrappers#COWing_Objects).

The relevant code ***is***:

```
var rv = {
    __exposedProps__: {
        finalUrl: "r",
        readyState: "r",
        responseHeaders: "r",
        responseText: "r",
        status: "r",
        statusText: "r"
        },
    abort: function () { return req.abort(); }
};
```

but ***should be:***

```
var rv = {
    __exposedProps__: {
        finalUrl: "r",
        readyState: "r",
        responseHeaders: "r",
        responseText: "r",
        status: "r",
        statusText: "r",
        abort: "r"
        },
    abort: function () { return req.abort(); }
};
```

See related bugs:

1. [Provide abort() for GM_xmlhttpRequest](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1007)
2. [GM_xmlhttpRequest response.responseText is undefined in...](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1607)
3. [Use **exposedProps**](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1595)

---

Patching the code fixes the bug.

You can:

1. Fork [the Greasemonkey code](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/tree), and use your own version (Recommended).
   and/or
2. [File a bug report](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues).